# I dont want the potplayer remember playback position in playlist

Tags: windows-10, audio, video, video-playback, daum-pot-player

I use translate software to dicribe my question, it may hard to understand, I'll try my best.

I creat some playlist in my potplayer(L1,L2,L3...) and I use hotkeys(like z is for L1,x is for L2,c is for L3...) switching in these playlists.

So when I playing a video in L1,I press 'x' key,then it will open and play videos in L2.

Now,the problem is when I switched to a playlist it always remember the last time (when i switch out this playlist) playback position but I don't like this.

For example:

1, I press '**z**' open L1,and played video to it's '1:00' position;

2, I press '**x**' switch to L2 and play another video;

3, I press '**z**' return to L1;

4, Potplayer will play the L1 video from '1:00' position;

I don't want to Potplayer play this video from '1:00' positon , I want it play from beginning '0:00'.I tried to disabled the option 'remember the playback position',but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Open PotPlayer >> press "F5" >> Playback >> turn off "Remember audio playback positions" (for audio files) and "Remember audio playback positions" (for video files)